# Ionic2 passing variable/array to function

Tags: arrays, angular, variables, typescript, ionic2

I'm VERY new to Ionic/Angular/Typescript...

I have the following button:

```
<button ion-button (click)="shareMe('hello')">Hello</button>
<button ion-button (click)="shareMe('world')">World</button>
```

And I have the following function:

```
shareMe(){
this.sharingVar.share($STRING)
.then(()=>{
    alert("Success");
  },
  ()=>{
     alert("failed");
  })
};
```

Basically, when I click a given button, I want to pass a VARIABLE to the function to process. The code above obviously doesn't work... but how do you do this in Angular/Typescript?

Is there a way to pass a variable $string to a function?

Please be as descriptive as you can. Much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the parameter to the `shareMe()` function.

```
shareMe(shareOption: string){
    this.sharingVar.share(shareOption)
        .then(() => {
            alert("Success");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            alert("failed");
        });
};
```

Update: added @Aluan Haddad suggestion because you are learning and this kind of things is something that you need to know now, not after you wrote 5k LoC.

Comment: Indeed this is quite correct. Consider improving your use of promises by either (1) using `catch(() => {})` instead of the second argument to `then`which has awkward composability or (2) using `async/await` with `try/catch`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not familiar with either concept you've introduced. Can you give me a bit more info, or point me in the right direction for me to learn? Thanks much.

Comment: @camaron, I get how you setup the function. How would I change the code in the button? This didn't work:
<button ion-button (click)="shareMe('world')">World</button>

Comment: Why certainly. I will create a gist in a little bit.

Comment: @camaron

UPDATE: Actually it worked like beautifully. I had a little bug. Thank you so much!

Comment: @frednikgohar you are welcome!, remember to mark the answer as the solution.